# SharePoint 2013 "new item" link bug

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having a problem with "new item" link in SharePoint 2013 lists. A month ago client found that when they are in a list page (AllItems.aspx) with additional document library webpart at the bottom, they cannot create list item when they click on new item (actually they do not see new item, but "new document" link), because somehow new item link has been rendered as document libraries "new document" link.

How can it be??

From inside server everything is alright and list has "new item" link while document library web part has "new document" link, but users which are connecting to SharePoint not from inside server they are facing this problem.

I have already asked what version of Internet Explorer they are using. All users use IE9. Also I asked to change IE compatibility view, to render pages as IE8, IE7 and other options (all options actually)! Non of them helped. Is it a problem with IE or is it a problem with SharePoint rendering html?

What possible work-arround or solution could you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the same problem, it has been lurking in SharePoint for some time and has been seen [before](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935504).  The options/fixes always seem to be:

- the view has become corrupted.  Does the 'New Item' link work while
  on a view other than All Items, if so, delete the default All Items
  view and create a new one.  That is the best case.
- Someone has added another list view to the page or replaced the existing one in Designer.  This can be tested and corrected as above
- Someone has used Designer to change the default New and Edit pages for the list.  The easiest fix for this is simply to recreate the list but that might be an issue if the list is complex or has valuable data.  There are some notes that mention an [alternative that can be done in Designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dszabo/archive/2007/02/20/custom-list-newform-aspx-ruined-in-wss-3-0.aspx)(see "Alternative Resolution") to reconnect the original entry forms.  I've not actually done that so I can't say whether it works or not.

Comment: Thank you for options/fixes. I will try to use first option to recreate AllItems view and will inform you if it will work.
About two other options: I didn't use Designer at all to do someting with lists/forms.